# Reading in Excel file XML into R dataframe

Tags: r, excel, xml, dataframe

I have an XML Excel file `data.xml` that I need to load into a dataframe using R.  Here is a simplified version of it, but for context, there are ~40 fields and 1500 observations and only some of them are populated for each row.

```
 <Worksheet ss:Name="sheet">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="50" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1500" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="58.2"/>
   <Column ss:Width="49.2"/>
   <Column ss:Width="70.2" ss:Span="1"/>
  <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">id</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">sex</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">dob</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">has_car</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">has_truck</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Female</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">01/01/1991</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Yes</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">02/02/1992</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="5"><Data ss:Type="String">Yes</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

My goal is to get an R dataframe that contains the following (please excuse the non-R-dataframe formatting):

| id | sex | dob | has_car | has_truck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Female | 01/01/1991 | Yes | No |
| 2 |  | 02/02/1992 |  | No |

I've played around with the package `xml2` read_xml function:

```
doc <- read_xml("data.xml")
```

This returns a dataframe with two fields in it (`node` and `doc`), both of which have a class of `<externalptr>`.  I'm struggling to figure out how to access the pieces I need from this, though -- I've tried several variations on the following line to capture the individual rows to be able to iterate through them in some fashion as a means of capturing the data:

```
entries <- xml_find_all(doc, "//Row")
```

But the `xml_find_all` returns an empty list of 0, so is clearly not functioning as I am aiming for it to. I think this isn't working because of the format of the data in my `doc` dataframe, but I'm not clear about what best next steps would be if I go this route.

I've also tried out pieces of the `XML` package:

```
xmlparsed <- xmlParse("data.xml")   
nmsp <- c(xmlparsed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")   
df <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlparsed, nodes=getNodeSet(xmlparsed, "//xmlparsed:Row", nmsp))
```

This does return a dataframe `df` with the following structure (one character column named `Data`):

```
Data
id
sex
dob
has_car
has_truck
1
Female
01/01/1991
Yes
No
2
02/02/1992
No
```

However, since each row has a different potential number of populated fields, I can't accurately use this method of reading in the data.

I have thought of using a portion of the code above:

```
nodes <- getNodeSet(xmlparsed, "//xmlparsed:Row", nmsp)
```

This returns a Large XMLNodSet (1500 elements), where each element is listed as containing:

```
:Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr>
```

Does anyone have any pointers of what I should try next?  The inconsistent number of Cells per Row are are really throwing me off for how to do this properly.  I think whatever answer I end up with must include referencing the `ss:Index` as well for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your XML-example to work when read in, but I saved the example-data in Excel as XML 2003 format and tried again.

The reason why you get a list of 0 elements when trying to read the `//Row` is because it should be: `.//ss:Row`, where the dot is the root node, // is all descendants and `ss` points to the namespace that identifies the ... SpreadSheet: data, rows and so forth. The file also has a `x` namespace, pointing to the schema identifying it as Excel - i.e. all metadata, settings, properties.

```
# Load the required packages
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(margrittr)

# Read the XML file
xml_data <- read_xml("data.xml")

# Define the namespaces
ns <- c(
    ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet",
    x = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
)

# Extract the rows from the XML
rows <- xml_find_all(xml_data, ".//ss:Row", ns)

# The difficult part: iterate through all rows
# find the cells
# use the ss:Index that is only there when incomplete row, otherwise = i
# Extract the data from the cells and store it in a list
data_list <- lapply(rows, function(row) {
    cells <- xml_find_all(row, ".//ss:Cell", ns)
    max_index <- max(as.integer(xml_attr(cells, 
                                         "ss:Index", 
                                         ns, 
                                         default = NA)), 
                                na.rm = TRUE, 1:length(cells))
    cell_data <- vector("list", length = max_index)
    
    for (i in seq_along(cells)) {
        cell <- cells[[i]]
        index <- as.integer(xml_attr(cell, "ss:Index", ns, default = NA))
        if (is.na(index)) {
            index <- i
        }
        data_element <- xml_find_first(cell, ".//ss:Data", ns)
        
        if (!is.null(data_element)) {
            cell_data[[index]] <- xml_text(data_element)
        } 
    }
    
    cell_data
})

# replace all NULLs with NA in the list, otherwise they will become "NULL"
data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(row) {
    lapply(row, function(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x)
})

# Remove the first element (column names)
# bind the rows
# name the columns
df <- data_list[-1] %>%               
    do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% 
    magrittr::set_colnames(unlist(data_list[[1]]))
```

This was quite interesting to figure out. I had to look up quite a few things to get the loop to function.